# Best way to discover creating events in calendar application

Tags: mobile-application, calendar, discovery, discoverability, long-press

I have a mobile calendar app

[image]

First I want to say that my app is not a normal calendar app, because users may **sometimes** need to add a lot of events at once, not like google calendar where people usually create one event every time they need, so I need a UI/UX that will make creating a lot of events at once easy and fast.

---

The user can press the 'plus' button in the top left corner, to toggle **Adding Mode**.

In Adding Mode, **single-tapping a date** opens the "New Event Screen".

But the user can also show the same "New Event Screen" **by long-pressing a date**, **without being in Adding Mode.**

1. What is the best way to indicate that long-pressing a date is also a possible way to add events? I find creating events by long-pressing way quicker than pressing the plus button and then single-tapping a date, especially if the user wants to create a lot of events at once.
2. Should I remove single-tap "Adding Mode" and instead only creating events with long-press? Because if I'll keep both ways to create events I worry it might be confusing for the user which way to choose.
3. Is long-press a good gesture for this kind of thing?

Any other advice will be appreciated!

Comment: there's no such things as "UI/ux"

Comment: If the page is designed to add events (and not view/browse existing events) then might as well change the long-press to a single press.

Answer (score 2):

I personally know much more obvious situations with large buttons where a normal user does not recognize the action to be executed. In the case of hidden actions such as the one shown on this calendar button, the long-press gesture makes it practically impossible.

---

In many games with free and paid versions, the free version is usually accompanied by an advertising that runs for a few seconds. This advertisement sometimes comes with music and voice with a disabled closing button `X` and a progress bar, a circle around the `x-button`. To mute the advertising, there's a `speaker icon` or nothing. But in some, the closing `x-button` with its progress circle flashes (fade-in-out blinking), which leads to think that it has a double function before enabling the button: taping the disabled button mutes the advertising.

---

Adapting this to the calendar, after the click that selects the day, it can blink indicating there's a second action waiting:

- The first click selects the day and stars fading-in-out
- The second click (or two taps, or long-press) open the options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Long press might take too Long

Instead of a long press, simply tapping (screenshot below) and then double-tapping on the same point on the calendar area should allow users to add(this is how google calendar does it). This pattern is intuitive enough and users would be more familiar with it than long press.

For adding mode, I'd advise you to keep it as it provides a visual cue to performing the same action.

[image]